# gpl-3 vs agpl for a telegram bot

Tags: gpl-3, agpl-3.0

I used the gpl3 license for a telegram bot.
I later realized that maybe it's not the best license since if someone forks my project, he is not distributing it, but it runs his own instance of the bot on his server and users contact the bot on telegram.

As far as I have read maybe the a-gpl license should better fit this case.
Am I right?

I would like that if someone forks my bot to create his own instance usable for users on telegram, he is forced to release the code and also to credit my project

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If that's what you want, then yes, the AGPL would be better. The GPL makes no restrictions on those who don't distribute the software but only make it available to interact with over a network.